FPS drop or Program not responding
I’m using a translation tool, apologies for any misunderstanding.
Yesterday, while I was working, my FPS suddenly dropped, or sometimes the program became unresponsive. At first, I thought it was normal since I was rendering 1 million objects. However, after I deleted the project and started fresh, whenever I clicked on any UI element or object, the FPS dropped again. I’ve tried restarting the program, deleting and reloading, turning off the computer, and even restarting the machine, but the issue persists.
What should I do?
